# Scrolling horizontal and vertical both direction

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have requirement to scroll the images horizontally and vertically.

I have sections which will `segregated vertically` and `in each section itself it will be so many images which will be scrolled horizontally`.

I made vertical scrolling using `UICollectionView` with [Ray wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22) but how do I get horizontal scrolling in each section?

Should I use any other object like `UITableView` or `UIScrollview` for this purpose?

Any tutorial available how to achieve this?

`Is it compulsory to implement Layout subclass or UICollectionviewFlowlayout when using collection view`?

**EDIT**

Till now I have implemented this code which scrolls vertically and has 5 sections each but not able to scroll the individual sections

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    NSArray *arrayReturn = [self returnArray:section];
    return arrayReturn.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{   
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"imagecell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSArray *arrSection = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self returnArray:indexPath.section]];
        NSString *fileName = [arrSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//               cell.imgVw.image = ;
               if([CollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]){
                   ImageCell *currentCell = (ImageCell *) [cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                   currentCell.imgVw.image = image;
               }

           });
    }];

    [self.thumbnailQueue addOperation:operation];

    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    HeaderView *Header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoHeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Header.lblHeaderTitle.text = @"Header title";

    Header.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    return Header;
}
```

Comment: Any screen shot that which exactly explains your requirement ?

Comment: its all are base on ContentSize of your ScrollView, so five proper contentSize of Your ScrollView and give direction lock of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Basically you need to do following:

- Take a tableView or CollectionView
- In each cell you need to add a scrollview with horizontal scrolling enabled.
- Add items to scroll view of each cell while creating cells and give the scroll view appropriate content size.

It will give you a desired result.

Comment: Adding a scrollview to each cell will lead to memory issues

Comment: It will increase the memory usage of the view but i dont think this will cause any memory issues. This is a similar case of using a custom cell having some view inside it.

Comment: But it would be better if i can use collection view as it automatically manages cell's height and width when orientation changes

Comment: As i said in answer you can use a collection view too with same approach. It also works based on cells.

Comment: This tutorial helped me but I implemented it as tableview with each cell having collectionview to scroll in horizontal direction. And this working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
**viewController.h**

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollViewMain;


**viewController.m**

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self createDisplay];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void) createDisplay
{
for(UIView *subView in scrollViewMain.subviews)
{
    if(![subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
int yPos =5;

for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
{

    int xPosition=5;


    UIScrollView *scrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPos, scrollViewMain.frame.size.width, 100)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;



    xPosition +=5;

    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {

        UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, 100, 100)];
        lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblTitle.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
        lblTitle.text = @"test";
        lblTitle.numberOfLines =0;
        lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

        [scrollView addSubview:lblTitle];

        xPosition +=100;
        xPosition +=10;
    }
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xPosition, 100)];
    [scrollViewMain addSubview:scrollView];
    yPos +=120;
}
[scrollViewMain flashScrollIndicators];
[scrollViewMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, yPos)];
  }
```